# UITableViewAutomaticDimension not working in Xcode 6.3

Tags: xcode, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint, xcode6.3

I updated my Xcode to 6.3 along with Swift 1.2, and I made the transition.

Everything works except dynamic row height for table view. I have those on 3 completely different table views, so it probably isn't something else influencing the bug.

I set all of the table views to:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

and all of my xib files are properly constrained.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you add an estimatedRowHeight? without that it will not work

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I simply added UITableViewAutomaticDimension to estimatedrowforindexpath as well. You can see how it works on the [BEAM App](http://beam.biz/app) (under 'people' category).

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you should provide an estimate. Additionally, according to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:), there are performance implications in using the callbacks instead of the `rowHeight` and `estimatedRowHeight` properties. You could set `rowHeight` to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, then `estimatedRowHeight` to an arbitrary estimated value.

Answer (score 3):

Estimated row height needs to be provided.

It is better not to implement `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` unless necessary.

`estimatedRowHeight` is cheaper provided you can come up with a value

```
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 30 //Provide any appropriate value
```