# why UITableViewAutomaticDimension not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, row-height

Hi there is plenty of question answering the dynamic height for `UITableViewCell` of `UITableView`. However I find it weird when I did it.

here's are some of the answer :

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565078/uitableviewautomaticdimension-not-working-in-xcode-6-3) and [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout)

usually this would answer the dynamic height for cell

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

but in my case I wonder this line wont do anything.

my `UITableView` is being viewed after clicking tabbar inside the splitview. Is this helpful?

Maybe I'm Missing something. Could anyone help me I spent 2 hours doing silly.

These are my constraint for title the title could be long but the label is not.

[image]

and this is my cell

[image]

Comment: You should double re-check with you `UITableViewCell` autolayout setup in xib/storyboard. You have some issue there 100%

Comment: yeah, Im rewriting it. Hope to find what causing it

Comment: If you post your xib/storyboard there, I can help you with it

Comment: Did you set your view constrains relative to top and bottom of your cell content view ?

Comment: should i just do screenshot?

Comment: Do you have constraint on a label with bottom space to superview ?

Comment: @zellb I think i dont have, hmm..why? maybe im messing something with my constraint

Comment: @caffeineshots Just to be sure I didn't ask for a title label but for the label below it? If you don't have it, add and check the result. I think it still wont work but show me your results first then Im gonna tell you the next steps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78077/discussion-between-caffeine-shots-and-zellb).

Answer (score 175, accepted):

In order to make UITableViewAutomaticDimension work you have to set all left, right, bottom, and top constraints relative to cell container view. In your case you will need to add the missing bottom space to superview constraint for label under the title

Comment: Note you will probably have to set the bottom constraints for some views to be >= rather than just = to allow them to grow with the dynamic height of the cell. This was the trick for me.

Comment: @khunshan Are you sure that you are not using size classes?

Comment: @ZellB. yea you are right. its due to a constraint was missing iPhone class. (Y)

Answer (score 33):

I had added constraints programmatically, and accidentally added them to the cell directly, i.e. not on the `contentView` property. Adding the constraints to `contentView` resolved it for me!

Comment: yes  we need to clearly know what constraint we use to what cos one constraint missing or added could cos ambiguity or not satisfied constraint.Thanks for answer man!

Comment: I know this is old but i dont think this is the correct way to do this. If you dont add the constraints to the content view. The view will distort when you open any editing style for the cell like Deletion or moving the row it self.

Comment: @Esko918 I think you are reading his answer wrong. He is stating that you need to add constraints to the `contentView`. I also accidentally added constraints to the `UITableViewCell` when it should be to the `UITableViewCell`'s `contentView`

Comment: Thats what I said. If you don't add the constraints to the content view then the view will distort when you selecting an editing style like deletion or moving the row. Your not supposed to modify the cells view directly since UIKit modifies the cells layout when you hit editing mode and the cell shifts to the right.Your supposed to add all subviews and layout constraints to the content view. Not the View itself

Answer (score 28):

To set automatic dimension for row height & estimated row height, ensure following steps to make, auto dimension effective for cell/row height layout.

- Assign and implement tableview dataSource and delegate
- Assign `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to rowHeight & estimatedRowHeight
- Implement delegate/dataSource methods (i.e. `heightForRowAt` and return a value `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to it)

-

**Objective C:**

```
// in ViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

  @property IBOutlet UITableView * table;

@end

// in ViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.table.dataSource = self;
    self.table.delegate = self;

    self.table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    self.table.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

**Swift:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Don't forget to set dataSource and delegate for table
    table.dataSource = self
    table.delegate = self

    // Set automatic dimensions for row height
    // Swift 4.2 onwards
    table.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    table.estimatedRowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension


    // Swift 4.1 and below
    table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    table.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

}



// UITableViewAutomaticDimension calculates height of label contents/text
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    // Swift 4.2 onwards
    return UITableView.automaticDimension

    // Swift 4.1 and below
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

For label instance in UITableviewCell

- Set number of lines = 0 (& line break mode = truncate tail)
- Set all constraints (top, bottom, right left) with respect to its superview/ cell container.
- *Optional*: Set minimum height for label, if you want minimum vertical area covered by label, even if there is no data.

[image]

**Note**: If you've more than one labels (UIElements) with dynamic length, which should be adjusted according to its content size: Adjust 'Content Hugging and Compression Resistance Priority` for labels which you want to expand/compress with higher priority.

Comment: implementing heightForRowAt  with returning UITableView.automaticDimension work

Comment: Don't return automaticDimension in the estimatedHeightForRowAt delegate method. It's there to hint to the table view the size of the cell.

Comment: setting the rowHeight and estimatedRowHeight in viewDidLoad solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 20):

Also make sure the Lines for your UILabel in the cell is set to 0. If it is set to 1, it will not grow vertically.

Answer (score 7):

I have a specific case, and 99% of the solutions I read didn't work. I thought I'd share my experience. Hope it can helps, as I'd struggled for a couple of hours before fixing this issue.

**My scenario**:

- I'm using **two TableViews in one ViewController**
- I am **loading Custom Cells (xib)** in those tableviews
- Dynamic content in cells consists of two labels
- Page uses a **ScrollView**

**What I needed to achieve**:

- Dynamic TableView height
- Dynamic TableViewCells height

**What you'll need to check to make it work smoothly**:

- Like every tutorial and answer will tell you, set all the constraints for your label/content (top, bottom, leading & trailing), and set it to the ContentView (Superview). [This video tutorial will be helpful](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1KJQs0frbM).
- In the `viewWillAppear` method of my ViewController, I am giving one of my tableViews (`tableView2`) an estimated row height and then use the `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` as such (and as seen in all tutorials/answers):

  ```
      override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewWillAppear(animated)

      tableView2.estimatedRowHeight = 80
      tableView2.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

  }
  ```

For me, these previous steps were not enough. My TableView would simply take the estimatedRowHeight and multiply it by the number of cells. Meeeh.

- As I am using two different tableViews, I created an outlet for each of them, `tableView1` and `tableView2`. Allowing me to resize them in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method. Feel free to ask in comment how I did this.
- One additional step fixed it for me, by adding this to the `viewDidAppear` method:

  ```
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  tableView1.reloadData() // reloading data for the first tableView serves another purpose, not exactly related to this question.
  tableView2.setNeedsLayout()
  tableView2.layoutIfNeeded()
  tableView2.reloadData()
  }
  ```

Hope that helps someone!

Comment: the last advice (but without double IBOutlet) is still useful in 2019.

Answer (score 7):

As of iOS 11 and Xcode 9.3, most of the above information is wrong.  [Apple's Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html) suggests setting

```
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 85.0
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

[WWDC 2017 session 245](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/245/) (Building Apps with Dynamic Type, about 16:33 into the video) suggests something similar.  None of this made a difference for me.

For a Subtitle style cell, all that's necessary to get self-sizing table view cells is to set the number of lines (in the Label section of the attributes inspector) to 0 for both the Title and Subtitle.  If one of these labels is too long and you don't set the number of lines to 0, the table view cell won't adjust its size.

Comment: Setting `numberOfLines` to `0` for **both** labels lets you get self-sizing with non-custom `UITableViewCell`s. Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## Forgot to remove `tableView(heightForRowAt:indexPath:)`

It could be the case that, like me, you accidentally **forgot to remove** the boilerplate code for the `heightForRowAt` method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 60.0
}
```

Comment: ... And of course do not give it a height constraint either ;-)

Comment: You can return ```UITableViewAutomaticDimension``` in this method. For subclassing

Answer (score 5):

For anyone that maybe faced the same problem with me: I struggled for an hour to make it work. A simple UIlabel with top, bottom left and right constraints. I used the willDisplayCell to pass the data to the cell and this was causing problems in cells height. As long as I put that code in cellForRow everything worked just fine. Didn't understand why this happened, maybe the cell height was calculated before willDisplayCell was called so there was no content to make the right calculation. I was just wanted to mention and probably help someone with the same problem.

Comment: Thank you! I too struggled over exactly this issue.  Seems like a UIKit bug to me, but this solved it!

Answer (score 5):

it was working for me fine in iOS 11 and above, while breaking in iOS 10 
the solution was to add

```
table.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
table.estimatedRowHeight = 200 // a number and not UITableView.automaticDimension
```

also make sure you add "heightForRowAt" even if it works in iOS 11 and above, its needed if you support iOS 10

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case i had two UITableViews, i had to modify this method as

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CGFloat height = 0.0;
    if (tableView == self.tableviewComments) {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    }else if (tableView == self.tableViewFriends) {
        height = 44.0;
    }
    return height;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, Simple solution it's work for me,

**In viewDidLoad write this code,**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{
[super viewDidLoad];
 self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0; // for example. Set your average height
 self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

**In cellForRowAtIndexPath write this code,**

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
  }
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0; // Set label number of line to 0
    cell.textLabel.text=[[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"menu"];
    [cell.textLabel sizeToFit]; //set size to fit 
    return cell;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

For my setup, I first double checked the constraints in the Storyboard for the `UITableViewCell` were unambiguous top to bottom, and then had to modify code in 2 places.

1. `UITableViewDelegate`'s `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)`

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
       return UITableView.automaticDimension
       // return UITableViewAutomaticDimension for older than Swift 4.2
   }
   ```
2. `UITableViewDelegate`'s `tableView(_:estimatedHeightForRowAt:)`

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
       return UITableView.automaticDimension
       // return UITableViewAutomaticDimension for older than Swift 4.2
   }
   ```

Step 1 and 2, lets you to apply autosizing just for particular rows. For applying to the whole `UITableView`, use:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
// return UITableViewAutomaticDimension for older than Swift 4.2
```

Answer (score 1):

An uncommon solution, but one that may save others time: in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` make sure there is no delay in setting your label text. For some unknown reason, I had it wrapped in a `DispatchQueue.main.async` block, and this meant that the cell was being returned before the label text was actually set, so the cell and label never expanded to the size of the text.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make UITableViewAutomaticDimension to work, you need to make sure all 4 corners' constraints is added to the superview. In most case, it works well with UILabel, but sometimes i find UITextView does the trick when UILabel not working well at the time. So try to switch to UITextView and make sure `Scrolling Enabled` is unchecked in storyboard, or you can also set it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I had three horizontal items and the most left had a constraint to left, middle one had top, bottom, to the left item and to the right item. The right one had a right, and left to the middle item. The solution was to add additional left and right constraints to the middle item (my label) that were >= some number to the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all views in the cell are constrained to the Content View and not to the cell.

As apple says:

> lay out the table view cell’s content within the cell’s content view. To define the cell’s height, you need an unbroken chain of constraints and views (with defined heights) to fill the area between the content view’s top edge and its bottom edge.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a new solution..that's worked for me.

basically `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` renamed as `UITableView.automaticDimension`... I hope..it wo

Answer (score 0):

[image]In my case I did everything but it did not solve the problem for me, at last, I checked the lines of the label which was fixed to 3. Changing the line value to 0 solves the problem for me. so to tell you all it must be 0 and constraints Top, Bottom, Left, Right must be attached to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

For recent version of ios and swift apple has changed the previously called UITableView.automaticDimension to UITableView().estimatedRowHeight, so to set the row height automatically use it like this:
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150 //random estimate manually to help the compiler before setting the estimate value.
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView().estimatedRowHeight