# Adjust cell size for large texts - SWIFT

Tags: swift, label, size, cell

I'm using "adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth" but the text is getting too small.

the cell need change according the text size.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as! DetailCustomCell!
    if cell == nil {
        cell = DetailCustomCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "myCell")
    }

    let object:PFObject = self.myComentarios[indexPath.row]

    if let comentario = object["textoComentario"] as? String {
        cell.userTxt.text = comentario
        cell.userTxt.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

How can i do that in Swift ???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30300870/1422333

Comment: One solution is dynamic cell height with auto layout :http://stackoverflow.com/a/18746930/452584