# UITableView custom section footer

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

We do have a `TableViewModel` which is implementing the `UITableViewDelegate` and the `UITableViewDataSource`.  It holds the sections and returns the right rows and elements of our `UITableViews`.

Now we want to have a custom table view section footer. Therefor we implement the `optional public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView?` so that this returns a `UIView` from a xib file. This is all fine but it ends up in a wrong footer height. If we use `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String?` the footer is displayed correct and the height of the footer is set correct.

So we also have to implement the `optional public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat` or the `optional public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat`

1. Question: How do i get the height of an UIView which this was instantiated? `view.frame.bounds` or `view.frame.height` is always 0.
2. Question: What is the default value Apple uses for the footer and how does it calculate that? I recognised that if we return `table.sectionFooterHeight` for the default (not our custom footer view) the hight is correct.

TableViewModel:

```
class TableViewModel: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var sections: [TableViewSection] = []

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sections[section].numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return sections[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section].tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        sections[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section].tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sections[section].headerText
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        sections[section].tableView(tableView, willDisplayHeaderView: view)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sections[section].footerText
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayFooterView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        sections[section].tableView(tableView, willDisplayFooterView: view)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldShowMenuForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return sections[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section].tableView(tableView, cellContentsToCopyAtIndexPath: indexPath, withSender: nil) != nil
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        ??
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return sections[section].footerView
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        ??
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to save your height in a variable when you set titleForFooterInSection? Something like: footerHeight = sections[section].footerText.frame.bounds.height , where footerHeight is a variable in your controller and you can use it as a return value for 'heightForFooterInSection'

Comment: Do your footers have a fixed height? Or is their height dynamic and set by AutoLayout?

Comment: Yes but that would mean that i have to set the height when i create the footer. I cant know the height of it on every device (containing strings so dynamic height depending on the phone size) Somehow the interfacebuilder of apple does set the hight on the default views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by adding the following method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return sections[section].footerViewHeight ?? UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

And returning the calculated height for the footer in section. It does resize properly and we are able to adjust it. As mentioned, returning the UITableViewAutomaticDimension requires:

```
// Returning this value from tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: or tableView:heightForFooterInSection: results in a height that fits the value returned from // tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: or tableView:titleForFooterInSection: if the title is not nil.
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using auto layout you can still return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` in `heightForFooterInSection` and the footer's height will be automatically calculated. As same with `heightForRowAt` , `heightForFooterInSection` must be used in combination with `estimatedHeightForFooterInSection`. A simple example would look like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 18 // or whatever value
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll give it a try and see how it works. Wi give feedback.

Comment: `// Returning this value from tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: or tableView:heightForFooterInSection: results in a height that fits the value returned from
// tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: or tableView:titleForFooterInSection: if the title is not nil.`

Comment: @BennX Where did you get this? In one of my projects this is working as expected

Comment: If you follow Xcode to the definition of `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` that is written there.

Comment: @BennX I can confirm for sure that `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` works with `heightForFooterInSection` if `titleForFooterInSection` returns nil and `estimatedHeightForFooterInSection ` is implemented. Also make sure that you have set all constrains correctly as described here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30300870/1422333